# It's possible to bypass CSRF protection Referer-Based by spoof the referer in browser victim ? (POST-Based)

Tags: javascript, csrf

It's possible to bypass CSRF protection Referer-Based by spoof the referer in browser victim ? (POST-Based)

Hello, i try to bypass a CSRF protection Referer-Based.
I know the basic knowledge to bypass this protection, but the request is blocked.

**This is a CSRF POST-Based.**

I have try :

1. Delete the referer > return 403
2. Add subdomain in referer > return 403
3. Add sufix into the domain like this vuln.com.attacker.com > return 403

finally, i came to the conclusion, that i must to spoof the referer head in browser victim, but i have found a sheet cheat, and into the this sheet cheat is apparently it would be possible to spoof a the referer with a POST Request by a pdf trick

https://2017.zeronights.org/wp-content/uploads/materials/ZN17_MikhailEgorov%20_Neat_tricks_to_bypass_CSRF_protection.pdf (page 30)

But i don't have this pdf CSRF :/

My question is : It's possible to bypass CSRF protection Referer-Based by spoof the referer in browser victim ?

For example, by CRLF like this ?

```
<script>

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'http://localtest.me/CSRF/referer-based/test.php', true);


xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Try CRLF to spoof referer
xhr.setRequestHeader("osef", "http://attacker.com%0D%0AReferer:%20attacker.com");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        console.log('Success ...');

    }
}
xhr.send("pwd=true&submit=y");


</script>
```

The test.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors','1');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
        <input type='text' name='pwd'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit'>
    </form>

    <?php

    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];
    $domain = 'localtest.me';

    if(isset($pwd) && !empty($pwd) && isset($submit))
    {
        $file = fopen('output.txt','a');

        if(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST) == $domain)
        {
            fwrite($file, "302 / ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\r\n");
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite($file, "403 / ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\r\n");
        }
    }

    fclose($file);

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't spoof the referer header

Comment: You can use the `<base>` trick (which works only in Chrome) to spoof the `Referer` header in GET requests. I'm not aware of any technique for spoofing that header in POST requests in any browser.